# Django user.is_authenticated is not for some subpage

Tags: django, django-templates

In my index.html(base template) have nav bar and user is_authenticated is not working for profile subpage it is working for home
**Index.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
...

 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link mx-1" href="/account/profile/">{{user.username}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item btn-danger ">
          <a class="nav-link text-white " href="/account/logout/">Logout</a>
        </li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/account/login/">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/account/register/">Register</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
...
</nav>
```

**Profile.html**

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block body %} 
{% for user_info in user%}
<div>
...
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock body %}
```

What i am trying here is when i login it remove login and registration button and instead whatever the user name and logout button is appear it is working on home but whenever i got profile page i see login and registration even though i am curretly logged in .

Thanks and any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your context data in profile? Also you can get user from request.user which is present in almost all django CBV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the authenticated user with `request.user.is_authenticated` in template. I think you can access the user in your index.html because you pass the user in context. With `request` you can access the user in any template without put it on the conext